# Matrix Multiplication of one Python DataFrame column while using another column to get a factor for multiplication

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, correlation, sumproduct

I am a noob, so some of the jargon used in the question is probably inaccurate and the formatting of the post maybe a mess. Bear with me. I am looking to do matrix multiplication on a dataframe column with an additional factor. Example of dataframe is attached in the image.

[DataFrame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K87iJ.png)

```
arr =(
    [1 , 100],
    [1.5 , 200],
)

df = pd.DataFrame(arr)
df.columns = (['A', 'B'])
df
```

Required Output:

```
100^2 + 200^2 + 2*100*200*(min(1.0,1.5)/max(1.0,1.5))
```

or

```
df.iloc[0]['B']^2 + df.iloc[1 ]['B']^2 + 2 * df.iloc[0]['B'] * df.iloc[1 ]['B'] * (min(df.iloc[0]['A'], df.iloc[1 ]['A'])/ max(df.iloc[0]['A'], df.iloc[1 ]['A'])
```

So it's like the productsum of each element of column with other with the corresponding values from column A being used to get the third factor in multiplication.
The columns have a few hundred values. Is there a way to do this operation with some Pandas function, without using too many For loops.

Comment: you should post the code to copy the data into an IDE instead of a picture

Comment: @aws_apprentice: thanks!

Comment: what does this look like for three rows? Your description of the operations wasn't too clear to me; alternatively write what's supposed to happen using subscripts.  Is it sum(Bi^2) +2*prod(Ai)*min(Ai)/max(Ai)  ?

Comment: do you mean this: `np.sum(df['B']**2, axis=0) + 2 * df['B'].prod() * np.min(df['A']) / np.max(df['A'])` ?